# Making jQuery Peity Bar Graph bars clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, bar-chart

Is there a way to make the bars of a jQuery Peity bar graph clickable?

I have created a 2 bar graph, and would like each bar to lead to a different link.

The most basic method I can think of is not working:

<span style='float:left;' id='" + id + "preProdBarGraph' class='preprodbar hidden'> <a class='button' href='http://www.foo.com'>0</a>, <a class='button' href='http://www.foo.com'>0</a>

And I am initializing the bar graph like such:

```
// set up the graph
jQuery(".preprodbar").peity("bar", {
      fill: ["#e71d32", "#FDD600", "#5AAAFA"]
})
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use [jquery's `.on()` handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind click events to any element to do anything.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click',''#leftBar',function(){
         // do something
         window.location.href = 'http://www.mylink.com';
    });

    $(document).on('click',''#rightBar',function(){
         // do something
         window.location.href = 'http://www.mylink.com';
    });
});
```

I don't know how that graph structures its html, but if each bar is a direct child of the `.preprodbar` class you can always use the `:nth-child(n)` selector:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click','.prepodbar :nth-child(1)',function(){
         // do something on the first child
         window.location.href = 'http://www.mylink.com';
    });

    $(document).on('click','.prepodbar :nth-child(2)',function(){
         // do something on the second child
         window.location.href = 'http://www.mylink.com';
    });
});
```

For the canvas element selection mentioned in the comments:

```
$(document).on('click','canvas:eq(0)' ,function(){
     // do something
     $(this).css('background-color','#f00')
});
```

This selects the first `<canvas>` that you created. Change the number in the `:eq(0)` to select any other, index is 0-based. If you want to bind the event to all canvas elements, simply remove the `:eq(0)` substring from the selector.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tjckobzp/20/

Comment: So here is what I have:  jQuery(document).on('click',"#preProdCrashesBar",function(){
         window.location.href = 'http://www.foo.com';
    }); And it is still not working.

Comment: can you please provide your html? paste it in [jsfiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or a similar service

Comment: Yes! So I put some code here: http://jsfiddle.net/simspc194/tjckobzp/18/ . In the JavaScript section, most of that is the jQuery Peity plugin code that is provided. Scroll all the way to the bottom until you see the "My code starts here" comment. Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: I see the graph plugin you're using creates a `<canvas>` element, which is pretty much an individual drawing. Making this clickable is not hard, but the problem lies in that you want different links depending on which area of the image is clicked. I'm sorry but I do not know about canvas enough to assist you with that. Try reading some online articles about canvas or posting a new question specific to links in canvas elements.

Comment: How would I go about making the entire thing clickable, though?